# 'Device Not Found' error when debugging Xamarin iOS in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.4

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using the following tools and versions:
Visual Studio 15.7.4 
Xamarin 4.10.10.2
Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Mac SDK 11.12.0.4
Xcode 9.4.1
Xamarin Forms 3.1.0

It all started when I upgraded Xamarin Forms.  It prompted me to upgrade Xcode in order to continue to debug.  I upgraded Xcode on the Mac.  Restart Visual Studio.  When I select Debug > iPhoneSimulator - I see IPhoneXXX iOS 11.4, but when I start debugging, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac on macOS?

Comment: Visual Studio for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by restarting the Mac server.  Ughhhhhhhh!